# Tools to find which files are only on one drive

Tags: file-management

I have an old backup of files and I'd like to know which of these files cannot be found on another drive. The folder paths could have changed, so I only want to go by file content and not file directory.

Do you know a tool to find these files that are only on the backup drive?

Comment: I have no direct recommendation (especially as you didn't name the OS it should run on), but I'd check with "duplicate finders". Some of them might have an option to list only files from the "current place" which do not have any dupes.

Comment: I have Windows, but in doubt could resort to Linux. I've tried some duplicate finders, but at least the ones I tried could do "comparison mode" - at least not directory structure independent. I'm think about writing a md5 Linux script, but some GUI would be nicer.